# What is the most reliable way to popup a window in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to popup a new window to open to some URL using JS. It will be triggered by a user action (i.e a button click) so it is completely legitimate. What is the most reliable way to display a new window that won't be prevented by popup blockers?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that NOT using a window would be most reliable.  Instead consider creating a dynamic overlay (an absolutely positioned DIV on the page) that contains your content.

It's a little difficult to get your head around at first but honestly not much harder to do and saves significant headaches.  Or is there some reason that you absolutely require a true window?

Any of the frameworks would make this trivial (and it's really pretty trivial in "raw" JavaScript but I use my own panel manager to abstract much of the annoyance:

http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_panelmanager/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sometimes this isn't an option, for example if the parent page is going to be reloaded, or if the user should have access to both (overlay will block the parent page).

Comment: @WesleyMurch I can't think of a case where this has to happen while the dialog is open.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer: Ebay's image uploader is one example. Another might be to launch a music player while the user browses the site (although there are alternatives to that as well, but it's an example).

Comment: Thanks Jim. I'll consider using a modal dialog (bootstrap/jquery UI makes this pretty easy). I guess one disadvantage of this is that they can only open 1 window at a time. If there is a big list of results, often people may want to open a few in a new tab/window.

Comment: @AndyHin Please tell us more about your specific usecase, it sounds a bit like you're going in the wrong direction.

Comment: Unfortunately once you get into "real" new windows you're always going to be under the thumbs of blockers.  You'll also have browser oddities (some open new windows, some new tabs, etc).

One thing you can do tho' is create a test.  When opening a new window have it inform the parent window that it succeeded (this might be best with a slight delay to catch those blockers that don't really "block" but just close newly opened windows).  Based that you might then create a modal dialog as a fallback or provide some feedback to the user informing them of the issue.

Comment: As far as opening a new window goes tho' - you're on the right track.  A button click is less "threatening" than an automated pop-up, never change domains between parent and child, partial screen windows with full chrome are better than full screen with no controls, etc.

Unfortunately in my experience most blockers just aren't that smart tho'...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). Depending on the user's popup setting, it may be set to block ALL popups. Using the jQuery Dialog, you are sure to allow a "popup".

Comment: Not sure, it seems your answer is the same as Jim's - using a Modal dialog. Voted you up.

Comment: Didn't downvote you, but I think jQuery UI might be a little overkill for a simple modal.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer You're right. However its really quick to integrate. ;D

Comment: @Markus It might be overkill, but the options are nice - plus, it also comes with built-in ARIA support and keyboard support as well. Depending on what he's building this modal for, it might be a good starting point.